# How to set maximum height of Horizontal Bar In MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library. In horizontal bar chart how to set maximum height of bar?[image] And how to set background
color of Bar.

Answer (score 3):

The height of the bar itself is calculated by the number of items in the `HorizontalBarChart`. There is no way to directly change that.

What you can do is make the entire height of the chart smaller if fewer values are in it.

Answer (score 1):

How to set the maximum height of the horizontal bar:

```scala
val barData = BarData(barDataSet)
barData.barWidth = 1.30f
chartIncidentType.data = barData // wherein chartIncidentType is com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
```